# VBA: Set Range Name with String variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue which appears to be simple, but I can't figure out what's the problem with my code.

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim ContractName As String
Dim RangeToName As Range

y = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    For x = 1 To y
        ContractName = Cells(1, x)
        z = Cells(Rows.count, x).End(xlUp).Row
        Set RangeToName = Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(z, x))
        RangeToName.Name = ContractName
    Next x
End Sub
```

I'm trying to name ranges based on the text in the "ContractName" cell which will change for each x.

But the line "RangeToName.Name = ContractName" gives me a run-time 450 error.

However if I add any other text in that line for example "RangeToName.Name = "test" & ContractName" everything works and my ranges are named with the full string of text including the text in the "ContractName" cell...

What am I missing?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `ContractName = Cells(1,x).Value` or `ContractName = Cells(1,x).Text` ?

Comment: @RubberDuck Hi, yes both give me the same 450 error.

Comment: @pnuts Hi, I'm trying to name each successive range (RangeToName) with the specific text present in the first cell above each column (ContractName).

Comment: A name must begin with a letter or underscore, does not contain spaces and must not be the same as a reserved keyword in Excel. In other words: A name can't begin with a digit.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank for the info! What about if the name in question also happens to be a cell reference in Excel, e.g. "KL2000"? Would that be considered as a reserved keyword? And if that is the case, is there a way to still use it as normal text?

Comment: @AxelRichter sounds like you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A name must begin with a letter or underscore, may not contain spaces, and must not be the same as a reserved keyword in Excel.

For example:

A name cannot begin with a digit.

A name cannot be "This is a test"

A name cannot be "A1"

"KL2000" is not usable as a name because would be in conflict with the cell reference KL2000, but "_KL2000" would be usable.

You should always attempt what you're trying to do with VBA directly in the Excel Application. If you had done this with a name like "KL2000", you would have gotten a meaningful error message.

Comment: Good information on this subject at [Excel Names -- Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html).